# Sending data from Android with OutpuStream to php

Tags: php, android

Hi and thanks for reading my topic

I'm trying to sending data (valeurDept) to my php file with the method POST but when i checked what was the value returning there's nothing but mysql errors

public class DownloaderSite extends AsyncTask {

```
Context c;
String address;
ListView lv;
String valeurDept;
ProgressDialog pd;
public DownloaderSite(Context c, String address, ListView lv, String valeurDept) {
    this.c = c;
    this.address = address;
    this.lv = lv;
    this.valeurDept = valeurDept;
}
//B4 JOB STARTS
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pd=new ProgressDialog(c);
    pd.setTitle("Fetch Data");
    pd.setMessage("Fetching Data...Please wait");
    pd.show();
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    String data=downloadData();
    return data;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    pd.dismiss();;
    if(s != null)
    {
        ParserSite pSite=new ParserSite(c,s,lv);
        pSite.execute();
    }else
    {
        Toast.makeText(c,"Impossible de télécharger les données",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
private String downloadData()
{
    //connect and get a stream
    InputStream is=null;
    String line =null;
    String param= valeurDept;

    try {
        URL url=new URL(address);
        HttpURLConnection con= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setConnectTimeout(3000);
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.setDoOutput(true);

        if(con==null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        try
        {
            OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(param);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();


        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        is=new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
        if(br != null) {
            while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line+"\n");
            }
        }else {
            return null;
        }
        return sb.toString();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if(is != null)
        {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

And here's my code of my php file which receive my value

I think that the problem is in the sending but my code seems working

[Php code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBX9g.png)

UPDATE :

I checked the value sending by my OutputStream and it's the good response we've got "Marne (51)"

[The pic here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mbz5j.png)

So why my $valeurDept in my php file doesn't became -> Marne (51)

Answer (score 0):

Use DataOutPutStream (platform Independent) rather than OutputStream.

Try this:

```
private String downloadData()
{
//connect and get a stream
InputStream is=null;
String line =null;
String param= valeurDept;

try {
    URL url=new URL(address);
    HttpURLConnection con= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    if(con==null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    try
    {
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream (connection.getOutputStream ());
        dos.writeBytes (params);
        dos.flush ();
        dos.close ();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    is=new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
    if(br != null) {
        while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line+"\n");
        }
    }else {
        return null;
    }
    return sb.toString();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}finally {
    if(is != null)
    {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
return null;
}
```

Comment: I'll try to use it and give you a response thanks a lot :) !

Comment: I put your code but it didn't change my response from my database,
i had the same error message from mysql, it didn't reconize my value "$valeurDept" i think that the php file doesn't receive my value but it's strange beacuse if I put directly my value in hard it's working.

Comment: @QuentinPetit Could you tell me what this function is returning (value of sb.toString()) ?